# How to change multiple textboxes from an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have a text file with names of different exercises. I want each exercise to be put into a textbox when I press a "restore" button. I originally has it as such:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("savedWorkout.txt");

            textBox1_1.Text = lines[0];
            textBox1_2.Text = lines[1];
            textBox1_3.Text = lines[2];
            textBox1_4.Text = lines[3];
            textBox1_5.Text = lines[4];
            textBox1_6.Text = lines[5];
            textBox1_7.Text = lines[6];
```

Doing it this way worked and updated the textboxes. But I also had a lot more textboxes so I wanted to populate each textbox in a loop to make the code more compact. So I tried this with an array:

```
string[] exercises = new string[] { textBox1_1.Text, textBox1_2.Text, textBox1_3.Text, textBox1_4.Text, textBox1_5.Text, textBox1_6.Text, textBox1_7.Text}

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                exercises[i] = lines[i];
            }
```

This does not work. Although there's no errors when I run the code it doesn't update the textboxes when I press the restore button. I am unsure as to why. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `exercises` string array only stores strings. It does not store or clone references to any `.Text` properties. Therefore changing elements in the array changes the array, but cannot change a TextBox. What you should do instead is this:

```
TextBox[] boxes = new TextBox[] { textBox1_1, textBox1_2, textBox1_3, textBox1_4, textBox1_5, textBox1_6, textBox1_7};

int i = 0;
var lines = File.ReadLines("savedWorkout.txt");
foreach(var line in lines.Take(boxes.Length)) 
{
    boxes[i++].Text = line;
}
```

Even better if the textboxes have a common parent control, like a GroupBox or Panel. Then you can do this:

```
TextBox[] boxes = ParentControl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
```

Just **be careful** in where you create the `boxes` array! Those TextBox objects *don't exist yet* when the fields of your Form class are first initialized. That is done later as part of the `InitializeComponents()` method. So make sure the array is either local to the method where you use it or initialized in the construct *after* the call to InitializeComponents().

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to search for the TextBoxes "by name". This way avoids the Array of TextBoxes, and would simply "work" if you add more TextBoxes to your form, and more lines to your file:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("savedWorkout.txt");
for(int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
{
    TextBox tb = this.Controls.Find("textBox1_" + (i + 1), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
    if (tb != null)
    {
        tb.Text = lines[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, and the excellent answers so far, seem to rely on the number of exercises in the *file* being the *same* as the number of text boxes on your form. But you also say:

> but I also had a lot more textboxes so I wanted to populate...

And before I ask "how many more" maybe when you're ready to take the next step you might consider setting things up to scale *automatically* to the number of exercises in the file!

---

**Textboxes**

A `DataGridView` control can be set up to provide the exact number of textboxes needed even if different files of various lengths are loaded.

*Your code uses `string[] exercises` and though this word has many meanings this example will take it to mean a "physical" exercise.*

[image: datagridview with textboxes]

So let's say you made a class called `Exercise` with a `Name` property (the value of the line you read from the file). To make things interesting you can add values for `IsDone` and a `Remaining` time property.

```
class Exercise
{
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
    // The "textbox" value from the file
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
    public TimeSpan Remaining { get; internal set; } = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
}
```

---

**Restore Button**

Now, when you read your file, make a new Exercise for each line in the file.

```
private BindingList<Exercise> Exercises = new BindingList<Exercise>();
private void onClickRestore(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SIMULATE THIS: string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("savedWorkout.txt");
    string[] lines = mockFileContents;
    Exercises.Clear();
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Exercises.Add(new Exercise { Name = line });
    }
}

// SIMULATED FILE CONTENTS FOR TESTING PURPOSES
// Names credit https://www.healthline.com/health/fitness-exercise/at-home-workouts
string[] mockFileContents = new string[]
{
    "Bridge",
    "Chair Squat",
    "Knee Pushup",
    "Stationary lunge",
    "Plank to downward dog",
    "Straight-leg donkey kick",
    "Bird Dog",
    "Forearm plank",
    "Side-lying hip abduction",
    "Bicycle crunch",
};
```

---

**Change multiple textboxes from an array**

When the main form loads, a one-time setup will allow you to load any length of file and have the correct number of textboxes. But as you can see the `Exercise` class can provide other useful properties that can be displayed in the same row as well.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        #region F O R M A T    C O L U M N S
        dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView.RowTemplate.Height = 60;
        dataGridView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView.SelectionMode= DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataGridView.DataSource = Exercises;
        Exercises.Add(new Exercise());
        DataGridViewColumn column;
        column = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Exercise.IsDone)];
        column.Width = 40;
        column.HeaderText = string.Empty;
        column = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Exercise.Name)];
        column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        column = dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Exercise.Remaining)];
        column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = @"mm\:ss";
        Exercises.Clear();
        #endregion F O R M A T    C O L U M N S

        // Make restore button
        const int DIM = 60;
        Button buttonRestore = new Button
        {
            Name = "buttonRestore",
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(DIM, DIM),
            ForeColor = Color.MediumSeaGreen,
            BackColor = Color.Azure,
            Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right,
            Location = new Point(
                dataGridView.Width - DIM - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, 
                dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight),
        };
        // Add restore button to DGV
        dataGridView.Controls.Add(buttonRestore);
        // Add click handler to restore button
        buttonRestore.Click += onClickRestore;
    }
}
```